# Algorithm of elliptic curve point addition in mixed Lopez Dahab-affine coordinates

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, elliptic-curve, ecdsa

In **Guide to Elliptic Curve Cryptography**, it provides the formulas to calculate the point addition in **mixed Lopez Dahab-affine** coordinates, as shown follows.
[image]

> In the actual algorithm,

[image]

The code involves additional conditional statements to handle some special cases.

> I am not sure what is the purpose of the condition block in `line 9`.

Could anyone explain the special case that this block trying to handle? Is this block always necessary?

Comment: 9.1 is for the case P=Q. 9.2 is for the case P=-Q. So unless you can guarantee these two conditions will never occur then yes, this block is always necessary.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Why P = -Q when X3 = 0 and Y3 != 0 ?